# Writing a Javascript function that resolves a promise when watch source becomes truthy

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to write a Javascript function that will watch a javascript expression and wait until it becomes `truthy` and then it will resolve the promise. The problem is that my `when` function never resolves the promise.

In the end I would like to use this function like this:

```
let myNumber = 0

setInterval(() => {
    myNumber = myNumber + 1
}, 1000)

when(myNumber === 4).then(() => {
    console.log('My number is 4!!')
})
```

Here is my `when()` function:

```
window['when'] = (watchSource: boolean): Promise<any> => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        let interval

        interval = setInterval(() => {
            console.log(watchSource) // <--- always false

            if (watchSource === true) {
                clearInterval(interval)
                resolve()
            }
        }, 100)
    })
}
```

Comment: You seem to believe that `watchSource` is evaluated dinamycally every time, but it's not. It's either true or false when you call the function. You need to actually go and look at `myNumber` everytime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
when(myNumber === 4).then(() => {
    console.log('My number is 4!!')
})
```

The problem with this is that `myNumber === 4` is evaluated as `false` when `when()` is called, and so `false` is then assigned to `watchSource`. Since `when()` is never called again, a new value for `watchSource` is never provided and it stays `false`.

---

One (of many) ways to solve this is for your watchSource to be a function. This lets you re-execute the condition each time you want to check it.

```
window['when'] = (watchSource: () => boolean): Promise<any> => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        let interval

        interval = setInterval(() => {
            console.log(watchSource()) // <--- always false

            if (watchSource() === true) {
                clearInterval(interval)
                resolve()
            }
        }, 100)
    })
}
```

Then:

```
when(() => myNumber === 4).then(() => {
    console.log('My number is 4!!')
})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAdwBYFMwApkEMoSoDKcIAThOgFyJYCUiAvAHyIBGccANurmHTQAKZOAFsYAZ3QAeAG5wYAE1YBvAFCJNiMuijkkYdMkTCxk9Fh0Tus9E1UatTnlEQwwUdGVm4uTRFJQAJIeXj5cWPT2iOpOcVoQCNY8AHRccADmOPiEJOSU9HRqjvFOMMC0eATEpBQWDIyNiFBkIOgMsaVdEDy4ZCGe3r5Y7oPhRV1dVjb1JZMAvnNO8wA0iACMAAybE1rzRYtqLoiiAJ4AciCibF7+m8WBA2HDUSwxc2eX17eMJxdXNzIiAA1Bs1KsNtsdsU0JhIg1WJ8AT8mgAWOgpKAYbCvBxORJgZLoNKZLAAcgAsqdEGBkUDJIhUQBCJlkg50IA)

Comment: Oh, you saved my day! Didn't think of making it into a function.

Answer (score 0):

The `when()` is called only once throughout the application unless you call it somewhere else again. So more appropriate logic for your case would be:

```
let myNumber = 0

const interval = setInterval(() => {
    myNumber = myNumber + 1
    if (myNumber === 4) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 1000)
```

If you want to implement some kind of 'watch' handler, I'd recommend using [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) instead.